# Google Proximity API, how to unregister a beacon and reuse somewhere else?

Tags: ibeacon, proximity, google-beacon-platform, eddystone

Google provides a method to register a beacon to their register using Proximity APIs.

the call used for this is

```
POST https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons:register in
```

```html
https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/reference/rest/v1beta1/beacons/register
```

However, there is no documentation provided to 'unregister'

question:

1. Is there any API?
2. Is it just enough to un-authorize?

Scenario:

1. Using a test account, the beacon device is already registered and authorized.
2. Production requires another account to be owning it. Guess, this requires unregister / un-authorize

which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the proper way to "unregister" a beacon is to decommission it:

https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/reference/rest/v1beta1/beacons/decommission

This is what Joe Birch said about decommissioning a beacon in his [overview of the Proximity API](https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-google-eddystone-with-the-proximity-beacon-api-bc9256c97e05) (a great read, BTW):

> Decommissioning a beacon marks it as having no further use, causing it to be completely disregarded. Setting this state is irreversible, so should only be done if it is certain to not be used again.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with this answer marked as "accepted", because it is set on the topic "and reuse somewhere else".
I think this answer is misleading and somebody might decommission a beacon forever even if he doesn't want it.
The answer of @MarcWan is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, at this time, there is no way to re-use a beaconID in the Google Proximity Beacon API. While decommissioning a beaconID will indeed cause it to be permanently "shut down" — nobody will be able to modify it or see attachments from it — you will not be able to re-register that device's beaconID again.

The correct way is to use the hardware manufacturer's provisioning app to give the beacon a new beaconID and then register that.

Comment: I've added an answer based on the addition of a delete method on the beacon resource.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure when it was introduced, but there's now a delete method in the beacon resource, as documented here: https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/reference/rest/v1beta1/beacons/delete

This seems to drive a need to update to the FAQ here: https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/projects-and-ownership
 about accidental registration to the wrong project.

Comment: Yeah this is much better

Answer (score 1):

There is a way explained in the Google Beacons Proximity API to "unregister" the beacon:

> Unregister a beacon
>
> Once a beacon has been registered, it cannot be deleted from the registry. There are two options for taking a beacon offline:
>
> Call **beacons.deactivate** to temporarily remove a beacon from service. Once deactivated, the API will not return information nor attachment data for the beacon. Call **beacons.activate** to return the beacon to service.
>
> Call **beacons.decommission** to permanently remove a beacon ID from service. Once a beacon has been decommissioned, you will no longer be able to use the ID it was previously registered with. You can provision the beacon with a new ID, and re-register the beacon with that ID.

But for what it explains it can only be deactivated temporarily with the first option, and with the second you might be able to unregister it if you change its ID.